# pip install .\scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I issue a command to install scipy see below

```
PS C:\Users\yosief\Downloads> pip install .\scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe
```

and I get an error-traceback

```
Invalid requirement: '.\scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe'
```

It looks like a path. Does it exist?

My ENV variable is set so I can issue pip install from

```
C:\Users\yosief\Downloads>
```

even though my python path is:

```
C:\Users\yosief\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be nothing wrong with the file path.  Your problem is with the package you are attempting to install.

This will fail because You are running Python 3.6 and you are attempting to install a Python 3.4 package.

You have three options to fix this problem:

**1)**  Just try `pip install` and the package name you want.  No need to download first it does it for you!

**OR:**

**2)**  Get the correct file.  From what I see you are running it should be a 32bit Windows 3.6 (or 36) version package.  Everything **must** match

**3)**  If you can't find your version but the package is Python 3 supported you can download the source and run `python setup.py install` and it should install.